# Error: Cannot find module 'C:\project\node_modules\cucumber\bin\cucumber'

Tags: protractor, cucumber

I am creating protractor cucumber project using TypeScript. While trying to run my cucumber test in protractor I am getting below error message. I have installed cucumber globally as well in the root of my project folder. Still getting same issue. :

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Below is my bin folder structure. I do not see any 'cucumber' file or folder. However, I do see cucumber-js file. When I copy cucumber.js file from dist folder the error goes away. But that gives some other errors.

bin folder contents:
cucumber-js
run_slave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there are issues with cucumber v4.2.1 on windows 7 64bits. 
For now please try the following:

1. Delete the existing cucumber folder from your "../project/node_modules"
2. Run "npm install cucumber@1.3.3." in "../project/node_modules"
3. Try executing your scripts now Check if the issue persists!

Comment: Here are the commands that I ran: npm install --save-dev cucumber   npm install --save-dev protractor-cucumber-framework   npm install --save-dev @types/cucumber npm install --save-dev ts-node npm install --save-dev chai   npm install --save-dev chai-as-promised npm install -g cucumber

Comment: Also, which version of cucumber are you using?
Because there are issues with cucumber v4.2.1 on windows 7 64bits.
For now please try the following:
1. Delete the existing cucumber folder from your "../project/node_modules"
2. Run "npm install cucumber@1.3.3."  in "../project/node_modules"
3. Try executing your scripts now

Check if the issue persists!

Comment: FYI: cucumber needs to be installed locally in the project, because it is required by your step definition files.